# Complex Numbers (Satisfies an Equation)

Tags: complex-numbers

> > Question: Find the values of the complex numbers u and v that satisfy:
> >
> > $$ u + iv = 2 + i $$
> >
> > $$ iu + (2-i)v = 3 - i $$

---

What I have attempted:

I let $ u = a + bi $ and $v=c+di$

$$ u = 2 + i - iv $$

Subbing this into the second equation

$$ i(2+i-iv) + 2v - iv = 3-i $$

$$ 2i - 1 + v + 2v - iv = 3 - i $$

$$ 3v - 1 + 2i - iv = 3 - i $$

As $ v = c+di $

$$ 3(c+di) - 1 + 2i - i(c+di) = 3-i $$

$$ 3c + 3di - 1 + 2i - ci + d = 3-i $$

$$ (3c + d - 1) + (3d + 2 - c)i = 3-i $$

Comparing Im(z) and Re(z)

$$ 3c + d - 1 = 3 $$

$$ d = 4-3c $$

$$ 3d + 2 - c = - 1 $$

$$ 12 - 9c + 2 - c = - 1 $$

$$ c = 1.5 , d = -0.5 $$

$$ v = 1.5 - 0.5i $$

Subbing this back into u

$$ u = 2 + i - iv $$

$$ u = 2 + i - (1.5 - 0.5i) $$

$$ u = 1.5 - 0.5i $$

$$ u = 1.5 - 0.5i ,  v = 1.5 - 0.5i $$

If this is wrong please let me know , and if it is right. Is there another method I could use to solve this problem that would make it more efficient? I always enjoy looking at different methods to solve a particular problem!

Comment: This is very correct ! Another method will be to directly solve the four equations for the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$ and use matrix calculations. But this is good and the answer is perfect !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you another way to do it $$u + iv = 2 + i \tag 1$$ $$iu + (2-i)v = 3 - i\tag 2$$ Multiply the first by $i$ to get $$iu-v=2i-1\tag 3$$ Subtract $(3)$ from $(2)$ to get $$v=\frac{4-3i}{3-i}= \frac{4-3i}{3-i}\times \frac{3+i}{3+i}=\frac{3-i} 2\tag 4$$ Now, replace in $(1)$ to get $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks correct, but I suggest a "simplification" (if you ask me):

From
$$
3v - 1 + 2i - iv = 3 - i
$$
you get
$$
(3-i)v=3-i+1-2i=4-3i
$$
and hence
$$
v=\frac{4-3i}{3-i}=\frac{(4-3i)(3+i)}{(3-i)(3+i)}=\frac{15-5i}{10}=1.5-0.5i.
$$
Now you can get $u$ in a simple way from the relation $u=2+i-iv$, and you are done.

Comment: Oh that was really slick! Thanks for the alternate method :)